# EmmetInstall from a list - VI/Neovim

Tags: vi, emmet, neovim

I'm setting up a **[neo]vim** dotfile and to do that I have the next list

```
let filetypesWithTag = ['html', 'htmldjango', 'javascript.jsx', ...]
```

because I use it in many places, with the same list I'm trying to enable Emmet

```
au FileType join(filetypesWithTag, ',') EmmetInstall
```

but it isn't working so here is the question, how can I achieve this?

[Here](https://github.com/arkgast/vim-ide/blob/master/init.vim) is the complete file so you can check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to already be using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), you can achieve what you want in this way:

```
" On-demand loading
Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim', { 'for': ['html', 'htmldjango', 'javascript.jsx', ...] }
```

vim-plug enables lazy loading of plugins by filetype. To set filetypes correctly for arbitrary extensions, you can leverage an auto command. Take a look at this example for the many variations of Markdown file extensions:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.{md,mdwn,mkd,mkdn,mark*} setlocal ft=markdown
```